# Android Studio Emulator not displaying Test ADS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, banner

## **Hello , my problem is that the emulator doesnt show my test ads , here is my code**.

**Activity**

```
    package project.chawki.anew.enwproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "project.chawki.anew.enwproject"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
}
```

**This is the error I got :**

```
08-01 10:00:53.160 3210-3367/com.example.chawkii.myapplication W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
08-01 10:00:53.160 3210-3210/com.example.chawkii.myapplication W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
08-01 10:01:43.200 3210-3210/com.example.chawkii.myapplication E/Ads: JS engine could not be obtained. Cancelling ad request
```

**Im learning developpement and I can't see the fault , also for The permissions they are good too , But my test ads do not load in the android device emulator. Any help please?**

Comment: follow this way @chawkii

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a lot of research , I found the solution of this error , The problem , it wasnt the code , actually it was in my emulator , I had to download the last API & also update the google play service to the last version so I could see ads

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem by downloading the emulator that has **play store mark**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your emulator (or your other devices if you want) as "test device". Test ads will show on test devices only.

To do this, you need to call `addTestDevice` when you are building the `AdRequest`.

Change this line:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

to:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     private AdView mAdView;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
         layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

         // Create a banner ad. The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before calling loadAd.
         mAdView = new AdView(this);
         mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
         mAdView.setAdUnitId("myAdUnitId");

         // Create an ad request.
         AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

         // Optionally populate the ad request builder.
         adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

         // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy.
         layout.addView(mAdView);

         // Start loading the ad.
         mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

         setContentView(layout);
     }

     @Override
     public void onResume() {
         super.onResume();

         // Resume the AdView.
         mAdView.resume();
     }

     @Override
     public void onPause() {
         // Pause the AdView.
         mAdView.pause();

         super.onPause();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         // Destroy the AdView.
         mAdView.destroy();

         super.onDestroy();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Sign into your AdMob account.

2. Click on Monetize tab.

3. Select or Create the app and choose the platform.

4. Select the ad format either Banner or Interstitial and give the ad unit a name.

5. Once the ad unit is created, you can notice the Ad unit ID on the dashboard. An example of ad unit id look like ca-app-pub-0664570763252260/3326342124

Create as many ad units required for your app.
android-admob-creating-ad-unit

Create two ad units, one for banner and other for interstitial as we need to use the ad unit IDs in the next section.
3. Creating New Project

1. Create a new project in Android Studio from File ⇒ New Project. When it prompts you to select the default activity, select Empty Activity and proceed.

2. Open build.gradle and add play services dependency as AdMob requires it.

compile ‘com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0’

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}

3. Add the Ad unit IDs to your strings.xml. Open strings.xml located under res ⇒ values and add the ad units of both Banner and Interstitial.

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AdMob</string>
    <string name="title_activity_second_activiy">Interstitial</string>
    <string name="msg_welcome">Welcome to Admob. Click on the below button to launch the Interstitial ad.</string>
    <string name="btn_fullscreen_ad">Show Fullscreen Ad</string>

    <!-- AdMob ad unit IDs -->
    <string name="banner_home_footer">ca-app-pub-0664570763252260/3326522424</string>
    <string name="interstitial_full_screen">ca-app-pub-0664570763252260/1769900428</string>

</resources>

4. Open AndroidManifest.xml and add the below mentioned permissions and other properties.

> Add INTERNET & ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions.

> Add google play services version meta-data.

> Add the AdActivity adding configChanges and theme attributes.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.admob">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>

3.1 Adding Banner Ad

Banner ads occupies only a portion of the screen. I am adding a banner ad in my main activity aligning to bottom of the screen. In order to add the banner ad, you need to add com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView element to your xml layout.

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

5. Open the layout file of your main activity (activity_main.xml) and add the AdView widget. I am also adding a button to launch another in which we’ll try Interstitial ad.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.admob.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/msg_welcome" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_fullscreen_ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/btn_fullscreen_ad"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>

6. Open MainActivity.java and modify the code as shown.

> Create an instance of AdRequest and load the ad into AdView.

> Ad the AdView life cycle methods in onResume(), onPause() and in onDestroy() methods.

package info.androidhive.admob;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;
    private Button btnFullscreenAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        btnFullscreenAd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fullscreen_ad);
        btnFullscreenAd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}

Now if you run the app, you should see a banner ad at the bottom of your screen.
android-displaying-admob-banner-ad
```

Comment: follow steps off procedures

Comment: first I would like to thank you for your answer , you resume all , but the problem actually is solved , it wasnt the code , actually it was in my emulator , I had to update the google play service to the last version so I could see ads

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added initialize statement.
Add this in onCreate(){

.....
....
 MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

}